# React Router browserHistory push and anchors

Tags: reactjs, react-router, anchor, browser-history, react-router-v4

When using `browserHistory` from React Router 4 to programmatically navigate to an anchor:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
...
props.history.push('#blah')
```

I can see the hash changing in the address bar, but the page doesn't scroll to the relevant anchor. I have checked it with standard `<a href="#blah">Blah</a>` and this works fine. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks :)

UPDATE
Just checked and `<Link to="#blah">Blah</Link>` doesn't work either... I am assuming react `Links` work using the history object too?

Comment: I am using browser router, that's why I am talking about browserHistory. And as you can see from my post above I have tried exactly the line of code you suggested (except `this` as I am using functional component)

Comment: @Aaqib that's incorrect. This is completely unrelated issue. Pushing path works fine, pushing hash doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation I decided to add a function to handle `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle event:

```
componentDidUpdate: props => {
  const selected = props.history.location.hash
  if(selected && selected.length > 0) {
    const elem = document.querySelector(selected)
    elem && elem.scrollIntoView()
  }
}
```

This solves the problem nicely :)

Comment: This works, I just had to use `querySelector()` instead of `getElementById()` because `selected` contains the pound symbol `#`. getElementById is expecting just the ID without the #. querySelector works fine though.